# ntdll!RtlIsZeroMemory releasing linked list memory in C [warning: Critical error detected c0000374]

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, free

I am trying to write data with a linked list structure. After writing the function used to apply memory for each node in the linked list, I started writing the function used to release memory for each node in the linked list, but it encountered an error.

#### test.h

```c
typedef struct snPng_block {
    uint8_t size[4];
    size_t  dataSize;
    uint8_t *data;
    uint8_t crc[4];
    struct snPng_block *next;
} snPng_block;

int snPng_new(snPng_block **obj, size_t length)
{
    if(!length) {
        return snErr_ErrNullData;
    }
    snPng_block *head = NULL;
    snPng_block *ptr = NULL;
    size_t index;

    for(index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
        if(head == NULL) {
            if(!(head = (snPng_block *)malloc(sizeof(snPng_block)))) {
                return snErr_Memory;
            }
            ptr = head;
        } else {
            if(!(ptr->next = (snPng_block *)malloc(sizeof(snPng_block)))) {
                return snErr_Memory;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    ptr->next = NULL;
    (*obj) = head;

    return snErr_OK;
}

int snPng_release(snPng_block **obj)
{
    snPng_block *ptr = NULL;
    for(ptr = (*obj); ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    return snErr_OK;
}
```

#### test.c

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    snPng_block *block = NULL;
    snPng_new(&block, 9);
    snPng_block *ptr = NULL;
    snSize index;

    for(index = 0, ptr = block; ptr != NULL; ++index, ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%"PRIu64" node: %p\n", index + 1, ptr);
    }
    snPng_release(&block);
    return 0;
}
```

The following are the results of my debugging using GDB tools.
I don't quite understand why this program generates errors because I check if each node points to an NULL address before releasing it.

```
Reading symbols from #output\main.exe...
(gdb) r
Starting program: E:\Projects\Shark_Coast\#output\main.exe
[New Thread 13724.0x8ac]
1 node: 00000244171955F0
2 node: 0000024417195830
3 node: 0000024417195890
4 node: 000002441719ADA0
5 node: 000002441719AE00
6 node: 000002441719AE60
7 node: 000002441719AEC0
8 node: 000002441719AF20
9 node: 00000244171994F0
warning: Critical error detected c0000374

Thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007fff7ab2f633 in ntdll!RtlIsZeroMemory () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fff7ab2f633 in ntdll!RtlIsZeroMemory () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007fff7ab383f2 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007fff7ab386da in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x00007fff7ab3e361 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x00007fff7aa55b43 in ntdll!RtlGetCurrentServiceSessionId () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x00007fff7aa547b1 in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00007fff781bf05b in ucrtbase!_free_base () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
#7  0x00007ff7f3653480 in snPng_release (obj=<optimized out>) at includes/image/test.h:53
#8  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at test\test.c:29
```

Comment: Maybe try freeing the data before the pointer, `free(ptr->data);`. You ahould free the data before freeing the node I'd imagine.

Comment: While not related to the problem you're having, it's not a good idea to put your function implementations in the header (.h) file, and also you should use an include guard if you ever plan to include it in more than one place in your code.

Comment: @l'L'l However, as you can see, I did not use data members in the structure.

Comment: @DutChen18 Yes, I agree with that, but this is the code I am temporarily using to test linked lists, so placing it in the (.h) file is also harmless.

Comment: Putting those two sections into the same file and compiling fails. There are no library inclusions, and compiler errors from several missing identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem exists due to the incorrect function `snPng_release`

```
int snPng_release(snPng_block **obj)
{
    snPng_block *ptr = NULL;
    for(ptr = (*obj); ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    return snErr_OK;
}
```

where there are used invalid pointers in the expression `ptr = ptr->next` after deleting memory pointed to by the pointers.

Also after calling the function the original pointer referred to by the expression `*obj` will not be equal to `NULL` as it is required because the pointer is passed to the function by reference.

Instead you need to write for example

```
int snPng_release(snPng_block **obj)
{
    while ( *obj )
    {
        snPng_block *ptr = *obj;
        *obj = ( *obj )->next;
        // free the memory pointed to by the data member data
        // if it also was dynamically allocated 
        // like free( ptr->data );
        free( ptr );
    } 

    return snErr_OK;
}
```

After calling the function the original pointer `block` declared in main will be equal to `NULL` as required.

Comment: I have modified the code to the one you provided and debugged it again using GDB tools. Everything is normal. It seems that I am not familiar with the memory release steps of linked lists yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `snPng_release` function is accessing the freed block after having already freed it.

In this for loop:

```
for(ptr = (*obj); ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
    free(ptr);
}
```

After running `free(ptr)`, in the next iteration it will try set `ptr = ptr->next`, but `ptr` has already been freed.

One solution might be to save a pointer to `ptr->next` before freeing it:

```
for(ptr = (*obj); ptr;) {
    snPng_block *tmp = ptr->next;
    free(ptr);
    ptr = tmp;
}
```